# change variables_color1.less on button click?

Tags: css, button, less, color-scheme

So I have a Weebly site, and there is a .less file containing the following code.

```
@LinkColor: #1A292E;
@LinkHover: #d8c792;
@NavText: #8d2424;
@NavHoverText: #d8c792;
@NavHoverBg: #1A292E;
@NavActiveText: #d8c792;
@Logo: #fff;
@HeadlineText: #fff;
@TitleText: #333;
```

Now I figured out this changes the main CSS, the @Logo ect... My question is it possible to change the codes above via a button on the screen. Like change it to variables_color2.less, which has different colors.